# JavaScript - Get Table Column from Index

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I need a way to grab a column based on its index.  The index number is from looking up a `<td>` and returning its `cellIndex`.  The reason I want to do this is so I can grab the `<col>`'s class and apply it to all its `<td>`s.  Each `<td>` needs the class applied since I'm using a library (List.js) and I won't be able to do any of the sorting/filtering/searching if the individual `<td>`s are not appropriately labeled (unfortunately, it won't work if only the `<col>`s have them).  Also, the `<col>`s do not have any other attributes added like ids, names, etc.

```
function addClassesToCells(table) {
        var col = ;  // hoping to identify col using index here
        var classname = col.className;

        // rest of function
    }

function getIndex() { // test function to find index
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        var td = "TD";

        if (target.tagName == td) {
            console.log(target.cellIndex);
        }

    }, false);
}
```

The goal is getting all `<td>`s under a particular  to apply classes, so if there are other/better ways to do this, then I welcome any.  Thank you.

Comment: You haven't attempted adding the classes yet, it's hard to tell which part you're having difficulty with

Comment: What's your ("*[mcve]*")HTML relevant to the question? Do you want the first function to receive a particular `<table>` element, or `HTMLTableElement` node, and then automatically populate the columns with class-names? Where did your own attempt fail? *How* did it fail, what didn't it do that it should have done? What did it do that it should not have done? What should happen with `<td>`, or `<th>`, elements that span multiple columns using the `colspan` attribute/property?

Comment: @JuanMendes: I'm having trouble with the first part where it says `var col =`.  Applying classes I haven't gotten to since I'm trying to target specific `<td>`s under a `<col>` first.

Comment: @DavidThomas: My question is that I want to just get `td`s from a `col` at this point, is there a function to do that using the column number? Because when it comes to the rest, I think I know how to go about applying classes to each `td` from there.  And I only took these two functions from several.  And the first `addClassesToCells` would be in a loop of some sort, I'm just figuring out how to get one `col` and its `td`s before doing the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of cols and tds, use queries and match the indexes.

```js
 var table = document.querySelector('table');

 var cols = table.querySelectorAll('col');

 var trs = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

 var tds = [].map.call(trs, tr => tr.querySelectorAll('td'));

 for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < tds[i].length; j++) {
     tds[i][j].className = cols[j].className;
   }
 }
```

```css
.a {
  color: red;
}
.b {
  color: blue;
}
.c {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="a" />
    <col class="b" />
    <col class="c" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Lime</td>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>Yellow</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, I really like this approach.  I do have some confusion: I guess I'm wondering why we couldn't skip the step with collecting the `tr`s and iterating over them later in the function.  If I omitted that and just have all the `td`s of the table, wouldn't their index/i still match up with the j of the `col`s?  What's the difference?

Comment: They would match up if you did `cols[i % cols.length]`. That would be a valid approach also. I only used the 2d array to make it easier to understand since it matches the table structure